# Format Buddypress Date Picker Output

Tags: buddypress

I've created a custom profile field for my BP users and I'm looking to show the value on the user's profile page. The code below does this...

```
<?php bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'field'=>'birthday')); ?>
```

...But it displays it as "1985-10-30 00:00:00".

How can I format this to display like this: "October, 30 1985"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if BuddyPress has built in date functions but [WordPress does](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) and [PHP does](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php). This should do it:

```
$bpress_date = bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'field'=>'birthday'));
// $bpress_date = "1985-10-30 00:00:00"; // test
echo date('F, j, Y',strtotime($bpress_date));
```

PHP's [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects [UNIXTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). That is why the date string is passed through [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). It does not work without that step.

You probably want to consider using WordPress' [`date_i18n`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n), however, which would look like:

```
echo date_i18n(get_option('date_format'),strtotime($bpress_date));
```

This gives you some ability to internationalize things as the date will displayed according to the blog's date format settings.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the PHP function date() to format the birthday timestamp.

Example:

```
<?php 
$birthday = bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ),'field'=>'birthday'));
echo date('F, j Y', $birthday);
//would result in October, 30 1985
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this only seemed to want to return the date "Jan 1, 1970"